# PYSPARK - Implicit conversion NVARCHAR TO VARBINARY not allowed

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have the file reference data in form as follows in source sql table and trying to load the data into varbinary and nvarchar fields in target table using pyspark.

** Note: the data is stored in varbinary(max) field in source table

I need to have a similar data loaded into using spark into the target table XYZ
but when pyspark runs and it throws an error -
**LOAD: Error An error occurred while calling o87.save.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 2.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 2.0 (TID 2) (ip-.....compute.internal executor driver): java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Implicit conversion from data type nvarchar to varbinary(max) is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query.**

I tried using binarytype() cast in spark  it generates data as - '[B@72116b0f' and '[5B 42 40 33 35 66 32 38 65 36 31]' in sparkdf
`DF = DF.withColumn(col,jdbcDF[col].cast(BinaryType()))`

final output in varbinary col - 'col1' in target table is - '0x5B424037633138396234'
but the I am not able to convert it back to nvarchar type as above as we need to store the data in above format in nvarchar or varbinary field only.

Need some help....

What I have tried :

1. using encoding and decoding to base64 to get the data as source data
2. using sql conversion - 'select cast('...' as nvarchar(max)) and convert function too

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @community bot : My basic question here is - 
how can I keep the data representation as shown in Source table col as it is in the target column using pyspark.